# Let $q$ be the largest prime factor of $n$. Suppose $\phi{(n)}|n$, show that $q\phi{(n)}|n$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $q$ be the largest prime factor of $n$. Suppose $\phi{(n)}|n$, show that $q\phi{(n)}|n$.

I got no idea for this problem till now. Can anyone help?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime numbers such that $a | c$ and $b | c$, it's true that $ab | c$. So since $q$ is prime, it suffices to show that $q$ is not a divisor of $\phi(n)$.

Comment: @T.Bongers But $q$ sometimes divides $\phi(n)$ in this situation. For example $n=18$, in this case $q=3$ and then $3|\phi(18)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Let $n=q^mr$ with $gcd(q,r)=1$.

Then

$$\phi(n)=\phi(q^m)\phi(r)=(q-1)q^{m-1}\phi(r)$$

As $\phi(n)|n$ we have

$$(q-1)\phi(r) | q^mr$$

Now, all prime factors of $(q-1)\phi(r)$ are less than $q$, thus relatively prime with $q$. Thus

$$(q-1)\phi(r) |r \,.$$

Multiplying by $q^m$ you get

$$q^m(q-1)\phi(r) |q^mr \,.$$

This is exactly $q \phi(n)|n$

Comment: In your second centered line, do you mean $...|q\;r$ and not $...|q^m \;r$ (after dividing both sides by $q^{m-1}$)?

Comment: @ijkilchenko  I didn't divide by $q^{r-1}$, I only used that $(q-1)\phi(r)$ divides $\phi(n)$ and $\phi(n)$ divides $n$. Dividing by $q^{m-1}$ also works but it is not needed.